# Calling a Matlab program/waiting its response in Java program

Tags: java, android, windows, matlab, android-studio

I've run into a sort of impediment. I am trying to have 2 programs run at the same time, working with one another.

One is a Matlab program that accesses a piece of equipment (lets call it a camera) to take measurements. The other one is an android app (android studio was used) that has to change in between measurements.

Basically, I wish to start my app, showing a specific thing in my screen and take a picture of it. Then, I want the image that I'm showing to change and take another picture of it. And so on and so forth.

I already have the Matlab program to control the camera and take the measurements as well as the app, changing images on button click. I need to somehow make this automated, having them interacting with eachother to be able to perform simulation with 400+ images/pictures taken. Obviously, this would be very timewasteful to do manually.

My questions here are: Is there a way to call Matlab in my Java code in android studio? Should I create another piece of software from scratch, just to do this calibration with the interaction between the two? If so, would Java be a nice programming language to achieve this or should I work with something else that you might think is more accessible or easier to use?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this but I have heard of it.

[See the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/execute-matlab-functions-from-java.html) for this very thing.

> You can execute MATLAB® functions from Java® using the MatlabEngine
>   feval and fevalAsync methods. These methods work like the MATLAB feval
>   function. Use feval and fevalAsync when you want to return the result
>   of the function execution to Java or to pass arguments from Java.

Comment: Yes, I have checked that out, or even [this](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html). Although, the one you sent me is to calculate stuff in java using Matlab, which is not what I intended. The thing that I also thought about during last night was that if the android is connected via USB, I need to send the request via USB as well, to the computer, in order to access the matlab code, since it's the whole program itself that I am aiming for. I'm still working on it, but thank you nonetheless!